# Sum of distances of 3 points from a given line

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider 3 points $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and a line $\varepsilon$, in the plane. If $A_iA'_i$, is the vertical segment to the line and $h_i, i=1, 2, 3$ are the heights of the triangle $A_1A_2A_3$ starting from the vertice $A_i$ then I would like to show:
$$\sum A_iA'_i\ge \min\{h_i, i=1,2,3\}$$

I have tried to do that using elementary Geometry (I hope I did do any mistake) as follows:

[image]

First we see that if line $\varepsilon$ does not have common points with the triangle then we can always draw a line $\varepsilon'$ parallel to $\varepsilon$ which have at least one point in common with the  triangle and the sum of distances is less than that of $\varepsilon$.
Suppose now $\varepsilon$ crosses the triangle and the lines $\varepsilon$ and $A_2A_3$ meet at $O$.
One of the feet $A'_i$ should be always inside the triange $A_1A_2A_3$, let's say $A'_1$ then the line $A_1A'_1$ meets line $A_2A_3$ to the point $A''_1$. So we have $\min\{h_i, i=1,2,3\}\leq h_1\leq A_1A''_1=A_1A'_1 + A'_1 A''_1\leq A_1A'_1 + A_3 A'_3\leq \sum A_iA'_i$,

as we wanted.

In case $\varepsilon//A_2A_3$ then again we have: $$\min\{h_i, i=1,2,3\} \leq h_1 \leq A_1''A_1 = A_1A'_1 + A'_1A''_1 = A_1A'_1 + A'_2A'_2 \leq \sum A_iA'_i$$

If the $A_i$ are colinear then heights are 0, so it is also true.
My questions are:

1. Is my "proof" correct or do you see any flaw?
2. I have tried to prove the above with analytic geometry (see figure bellow) but I stuck.... providing a robust inequality, any advise would be appreciated
   [image]
   $$\sum A_iA'_i=\frac{|A\cdot 0+B\cdot 0+ C|+|A\cdot b+B\cdot 0+C|+|A\cdot c_1+B\cdot c_2+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\ge???$$

Comment: 1. If all the points lie on the same side of the line, then claim is correct (show it). 2. If the points lie on different sides of the line we always can mark alone point as $A_1$ and two other as $A_2$ and $A_3$. Then you can use your approach. You need to correct: $A_1 A'_1 +A'_1 A_1'' \leq A_1 A'_1 + \max\{A_2A'_2, A_3A'_3\} \leq A_1 A'_1 + A_2A'_2 + A_3A'_3$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, Thanks for the feedback. When you say  **"If all the points lie on the same side of the line"**, with respect to what point? $O$ ? Or do you mean on the same semi plane?

Comment: I've meant semi-plane as side in my comment.